# AngularJS (Post Method are not allowed)

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, xampp

I'm trying to insert data into mySql database but failed,I have been trying for hours and no luck please help me.
The error console said angular.js:12011 POST http://localhost:8000/insert.php 405 (Method Not Allowed).
I'm using Xampp.
Here are my codes

view1.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp.view1" ng-controller="empcontroller">
    <form>
        Employe No. <input type="text" ng-model="fName" /><br/>
        First Name. <input type="text" ng-model="lName" /><br/>
        Last Name.  <input type="text" ng-model="eMail" /><br/>
        Department. <input type="text" ng-model="userName" /><br/>
        Department. <input type="text" ng-model="passWord" /><br/>
        Department. <input type="text" ng-model="tel" /><br/>

         <button ng-click='SignUp();' >Submit</button><br>
    </form> 
</div>
```

view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'empcontroller'
  });
}])

.controller('empcontroller', function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.errors = [];
                $scope.msgs = [];
                $scope.SignUp = function() {

                    $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                    $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);

                    $http.post('insert.php', {'fName': $scope.fName,
            'lName': $scope.lName,
            'Lastname': $scope.last_name,
            'eMail': $scope.eMail,
            'userName': $scope.userName,
            'passWord': $scope.passWord,
            'tel': $scope.eMail}
                    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.msg != '')
                        {
                            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
                        $scope.errors.push(status);
                    });
                }
});
```

insert.php

```
<?php
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $fName  = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fName);
    $lName= mysql_real_escape_string($data->lName);
    $eMail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->eMail);
    $userName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->userName);
$passWord= mysql_real_escape_string($data->passWord);
$tel = mysql_real_escape_string($data->tel);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('MiddleWork', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from UserTest where Username ="' . $userName . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

if ($res['cnt'] == 0) {
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO UserTest (Username,Password,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Tel) values ("' . $userName . '","' . $passWord . '","' . $fName . '","' . $lName . '","' . $eMail . '","' . $tel . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
    if ($qry_res) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    } else {
        $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    }

} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
?>
```

Comment: So, two choices: reconfigure the server to allow POST, or use GET or PUT.

Of course, it appears to me that you're actually trying to use STDIN, which might very well be the source of the error message....

Comment: Thanks for comment but GET and PUT still doesn't work :(

Comment: Same error message?

Comment: Yes sir, angular.js:12011 PUT http://localhost:8000/insert.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: And GET?  Same error?

Comment: 3 methods caused same error, do I have to do anything ? please help me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125442/discussion-between-kitsakorn-p-and-kkinsey).

Comment: I am there now.

Comment: You need to specify Content-Type in your request.

Comment: Check your server error log. That should at least tell you why the POST method is not supported. Your entire problem appears to be server-side in nature so you need to focus your attention there

Comment: @IvanMalenko no, they do not. Angular by default sends HTTP data as `application/json`

Comment: in my terminal it said 404 insert.php not found. So where do I have to put my php file at or I did something wrong ?

Comment: @KitsakornP is XAMPP running on port 8000 and is `insert.php` in your document root? Are you sure you're not using a NodeJS HTTP server to run your Angular app?

Comment: I have insert.php in many direction because I was confused and I have one in my htdocs folder. I start monitor my project by typing npm start in terminal sir.

Comment: Ok, so your Angular app is running in a NodeJS HTTP server on port 8000. This will **not** execute PHP scripts. Easiest thing to do would be drop your Angular app into XAMPP's `htdocs` folder and run it from there

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: {
            fName: $scope.fName,
            lName: $scope.lName,
            Lastname: $scope.last_name,
            eMail: $scope.eMail,
            userName: $scope.userName,
            passWord: $scope.passWord,
            tel: $scope.eMail
        }
    }).success(function(data){

    })
```

And in your php file:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$fName  = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fName);
```